# Can we write gradle.build tasks some where and call them from gradle.build file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Writing tasks in gradle.build file is common thing, but what if they are huge and messy.

Is there any thing like writing tasks in other files and call them when ever necessary.

Comment: you should move your tasks definition outside the `build.gradle` and use `buildSrc` as described in this documentation : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources

Answer (score 0):

use one common `build.gradle` on top level of project and one `build.gradle` in every module and it will save you a lot nervs, mess and mainateinance issues. Here is some example:

```
project
 -> build.gradle
 -> settings.gradle
 -> src
     -> main
         -> java
             -> com
                 -> enterprise
                     -> build.gradle
                     -> SomeClass.java
                 -> internal
                     -> build.gradle
                     -> SomeClass.java
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build files become huge and messy, you are probably doing something wrong.

Some recommendation:

- read the Gradle [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html) to learn standards and conventions
- prefer standards and conventions over custom implementations and solutions
- use common tasks and plugins for common topics
- use [multi-projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) builds and utilize cross project configuration
- write custom [tasks](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-tasks/) for project specific topics if needed
- write custom [plugins](https://guides.gradle.org/implementing-gradle-plugins/) for topics across projects if needed